# how to avoid repeation using group_concat() in MYSQL query

Tags: php

i need help i tried everything but nothing happen don't know what happen here 
This is my db structure :

Below is my query

```
  $q = "select distinct section_permissions.user_id ,section_permissions.assigned_for  , u1.f_name as first , u1.l_name as last , u2.f_name as name1 , u2.l_name as name2  from section_permissions  join users u1 on ( u1.user_id = section_permissions.user_id ) join users u2 on ( u2.user_id = section_permissions.assigned_for )  where section_permissions.user_id != 1 and assigned_for =  ".(isset($_POST['assigned_for']) ? $_POST['assigned_for'] : 0);
                $check = $this->section_permission_model->q($q);
```

same on march if i assign different section_id to different user_id 
then also it combines i don't want that
please help me it display same as insert in db 
and if user_id =4 is assigned two section then display as 1,2 only on that month not always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the DISTINCT option with GROUP_CONCAT like:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT col_name);
```

Comment: i already use this group_concat(distinct section_permissions.section_id) as sections in my query

Comment: But there is no group by used in your query

Comment: That's great, by the way your name is meow? :D :P